# select from hdf5 apply function (e.g. mean)

Tags: pandas

I'm loading a data frame stored on disk as an HDF5 file. I'm using the store.select statement to run conditions and return only the data I'm interested in. After that I'm getting the column-wise mean of the data. Is there a way to combine the two steps such that the mean is basically performed on disk and the whole data is not loaded into memory at the same time?

Thanks!
-Kaushik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory yes, see [here](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/expr_class.html). In practice, not at the moment. You would have to drop down to pytables by using the `store._handle` to get at the data that is needed. You would also have to handle `nan`, for example.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! This encourages me to look into numexpr too, when I have homogenous data.

Comment: Here's the open issue thats about this (as well as some strategies): https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3202. Its important, and not too difficult.